# Multi tenancy support for SSO in Spring Boot with Active Directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, active-directory, multi-tenant

We have a requirement to isolate the tenant based authentication(SSO) using spring boot. few of tenants with Active directory, few with OAuth and few with some other SSO providers. I did not find a solution for multi tenancy SSO with Active directory. Would be really helpful if I can get suggestions on how or any reference solution for this requirement.

I found references for multi tenancy with OAuth but not with Active directory. I am expecting the isolation with tenant wise SSO with different SSO providers with spring boot specifically with active directory.